# Why does my Alexa skill test shows correct lambda output but gives an error message when tested in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to enhance my Alexa skill (based on a sample Alexa skill code) with a bit of SSML. When I run the test in the lambda function, I get a successful output however when I test it in the Amazon developer portal I get:

> The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.

Here is the only code I've modified to add SSML to my Alexa skill:

```
// Create speech output
var speechOutput = {
    speech: "<speak> Reflect upon <break time=\"10ms\"/> this. <break time=\"1s\"/>"
        + "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/findyourzen/audio/bell.mp3'/>"
        + fact
        + "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/findyourzen/audio/bell.mp3'/>"
        + "</speak>",
      type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.SSML
    };
    response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, "FindYourZen", speechOutput);
};
```

I have added the audio file exactly according to the [Amazon directions](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#audio) so I know that is not the reason for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ASK sdk v2. You don't need to add speak tag, it's automatically added. Try this..

```
         var speechOutput = "Reflect upon <break time=\"10ms\"/> this. <break time=\"1s\"/>"
        + "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/findyourzen/audio/bell.mp3'/>"
        + fact
        + "<audio src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/findyourzen/audio/bell.mp3'/>"

          return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechOutput)
                .getResponse();
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue like this before. However before I can help you I need to see the output that you get from Lambda when you test your code. The json it returns is most likely invalid. Either in syntax or simply it is not in the format Alexa understands. If you post it I can help you more.